# Countable Sets and Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i'm working on a question here and don't exactly know how to answer it.

"Prove that the set {$1/x$ | $x ∈ ℕ+$} = {$1/1$, $1/2$, $1/3$,...} is countable by:

A) By describing a way to list the elements.

B) By giving an explicit function and showing that it is a bijection."

For A) I was just planning on writing "{$1/1$, $1/2$, $1/3$, $1/4$,..., $1/x$} for any $x >= 0$."

For B) I currently have $1/(x + 1)$ for any $x >= 0$ then I was going to use that to figure out if it's injective/surjective, but i'm not sure if that is a valid function of the set in question.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you are working with $x\in \Bbb N^+$, you don't need to worry about zero.  Will $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ give a function from $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ to $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots\}$?  If $f(x)=f(y)$ does it imply that $x=y$?  If you have some fraction $y\in\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots\}$, what value of $x$ will have it be that $f(x)=y$?  Is that value of $x$ actually going to be in $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$?  Answer why to each of those questions to complete.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is specified as in $\Bbb N+$, so $0$ is not a permitted value.  You should have dots after $1/x$ in your answer to A.  For B you meant $1/(x+1)$, which is not what you wrote.  As $x=0$ is not permitted, this will not cover $1/1$ and needs a small update.  To prove it a bijection, go back to the definition.  If I give you an element of the set, say $1/12345$, can you find the $x$ it corresponds to?  That proves surjection.  Then take two different elements of the set and show the $x$'s they correspond to are different.  That proves injection.

Comment: So should I just be using $1/x$ as my function?

Comment: Yes, you should

Answer (score 0):

To part A, I would do the same as you.

To prove that it is countable using bijection, all you have to do is create a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, where the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and the range is the set you have asked for

Comment: So my function should just be $1/x$ instead of $1/(x + 1)$?

Comment: yes..if you google the term countable infinity you get "A set is countably infinite if its elements can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the set of natural numbers. In other words, one can count off all elements in the set in such a way that, even though the counting will take forever, you will get to any particular element in a finite amount of time". And that is what I get.